# How to open a password protected .sav (spss) file in R

Tags: r, spss, password-protection, r-haven

I have a .sav (SPSS) data file. The file is password protected, and I have the password. I do not have SPSS.

I typically use the `haven` package (`read_sav()`) to import `.sav` files into `R`; however, I cannot find a reference for how to unlock the file with the password.

No mention of "password" exists in the `haven` [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/haven/haven.pdf), so I suspect I will need either another package or script to supplement.

**Can `haven` unlock data with passwords (if so how)?**
Is there another option to access the `.sav` data and provide the same data format as `haven::read_sav()`:

> A tibble, data frame variant with nice defaults.
> Variable labels are stored in the "label" attribute of each variable.

The format is important because I have existing scripts that assume the format of the data matches the labelled-variables format from `haven::read_sav()`.

Comment: The function `read.sav` of the `readspss` package (https://github.com/JanMarvin/readspss  ) has a `pass` option. From the help: If encrypted sav should be imported, this is a maximum of ten character encryption key).

Comment: @MarcoSandri This opens the file (thx).  The variables are in a different format than ``haven`` but I should be able to work around that.  I thought about using ``readspss::read.sav`` to unlock the file, ``readspss::write.sav`` to save an unlocked copy, then ``haven::read_sav``for formatting to avoid rewriting analysis scripts, but ``readspss::write.sav`` throws an error "label and ncols differ. each col needs a label". I'm not sure if that's a problem with the original file or format of the imported data after ``read.sav``. I'll post back if I figure it out.